# autocomplete in Hotmail (address To), how it is working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I specially has used hotmail and I like its autocomplete for To Address. It works very nice like it not only shows saved contacts but also suggests address on which I have sent email but they are not saved in contacts.

The most important thing is it is very fast. It is not ajaxtoolkit's automcplete what is this control. Plz guide me about its implementation I have to do same in a web.

thanks Thanks THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are not doing any ajax. When I checked it through firebug I could not see any network call while typing in To box. I think they are downloading entire address book to client side at startup, thus reducing any further ajax call for To box. Didn't dissect it further.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep but I even checked html source. There were no addresses in the html code.

Comment: Decided to dig it further. As guessed these guys are downloading it at startup. They are hitting "http://by2msg3020609.by2.gateway.edge.messenger.live.com/actions/signin/" url with JSON data like this "{"authInfo":{"authType":1,"ticket":null},"clientType":2,"clientVersion":"4.2.0.0","compatibilityVersion":0,"domain":"mail.live.com","endpointId":"{08157249-f809-4508-a7c8-c63b6ce37981}","endpointName":"Messenger on the web","experienceId":null,"services":1,"status":1,"version":"4.2","market":"en-us"}".